# Как реализовать си указатели на java

Tags: c, указатели, java

Помогите реализовать си функцию на java

```
double FindMax(double ht,double *arg)//ht шаг,arg значение аргумента 
{
double t, act, max;
max = ft(0);
*arg = 0;
for (t = ht; t < tmax; t += ht)
if ((act = ft(t)) > max)
{
max = act;
*arg = t;
}
return max;
};
```

И вызвать эту функцию, изменяя значения шага

```
fmax1 = FindMax(ht,&arg1);
fmax2 = FindMax(ht / 2.0,&arg2);
fmax3 = FindMax(ht / 3.0,&arg3);
```

Answer (score 3):

Здесь проблема не в указателе, а в том, что по сути сишная функция возвращает 2 значения - значение максимума и значение аргумента при котором достигается максимум. Я бы посоветовал возвращать структуру/класс:

```
static class MyStruct {
   public double max;
   public double argument;
}

MyStruct findMax(double step) {
  //...
}
```

Тогда вызов будет типа:

```
MyStruct myStruct=findMax(ht);
System.out.println("Max ="+myStruct.max+", argument="+myStruct.argument);
```